# Is it possible to monitor SMART disk information from a VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, monitoring, disk-smart

I am working on a server ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

In fact i don't have an access to the server itself, but at a VM.
I am trying to monitor SMART disk information (like Temperature_Celsius and othet stuff like that) but only from the VM.

I think it is impossible because the VM havent any real access to the physical server, but I am not sure of it.

Thank you for read and i hope someone could answer me fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work provided that the VM "owns" the disk and the virtualisation engine permits arbitrary commands to be sent to the disk. In the mass-hosting case where multiple virtual machines are sharing a disk, that's a no-go, but it can be viable for custom configurations.

For example, you can use VMWare to pass-through a USB-SATA converter to the guest. Provided the guest supports sending SMART commands to USB Mass Storage devices — and anything you're likely to run in 2014 will have this support — you're good.